# data sorting on y axis of Stacked Bar Chart in d3 ( x axis is already sorted)

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, graph, bar-chart

I am using [Stacked Bar Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208) example for my work but I also want to sort my data on y axis. I dont know how this is possible, because data is associated with keys [samples] for filling the colors.

any suggestion will be appreciated? how it can be done.
Following is the screen shot of my example. Suppose here I want to sort each blood sample according to amount. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution for it, here. [link to example](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/57ea97bc0f0bb5bb4405).by [Lars](https://gist.github.com/larskotthoff)

this example doesn't use d3.layout.stack. but it is same, what I was looking for.